# Angular 8 DomSanitizer whitelist?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-dom-sanitizer

Im using angular(8) in my web page and would like to display several `iframe`s as `innerHTML`.

By default the angular domsanitizer removes risky elements. I know I can disable this by using the `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` functions and alike.
(https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)

Since the content will be user generated however, I cannot simple bypass the Domsanitizer, as it is too risky. However I wonder if it's possible to allow certain domains that are known, like my own domain for example.
So I would need to give the Sanitizer some kind of whitelist with secure domains. Google did not return anything useful so far, so I wonder:
Is that possible and if yes, how would I do that?

Comment: You could create a pipe that allows the `[innerHtml]` of the `<iframe>` by bypassing the DomSanitizer.  https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/angular-safe-pipe-implementation-to-bypass-domsanitizer-stripping-out-content-c1bf0f1cc36b

Comment: Thanks but that is not the issue. The issue is that DomSanitizer erases the iframe completely or if bypassed, not at all. 
But I want it to remove it always if the src is not within a whitelist.

I digged deeper into the code and it seems, it removes the iframe tag without even looking at the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is hard to do this in Angular unless you implement your own DomSanitizer. Based on the source code [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8.1.x/packages/core/src/sanitization/html_sanitizer.ts#L69), the iframe is not in whiltelist. The filtering rule seems not possible to extend. I suggest you did the filtering here by your self, or using some third-party lib like [js-xss](https://github.com/leizongmin/js-xss) which allow you to define the whilelist.

Comment: link only answers may not work as links may become broken - welcome to Stack Overflow :)